# SQL question. Find the two person having same hobbies in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE [tbl_hobby]

person_id (int) , hobby_id(int)

has many records. I want to get a SQL query to find all pairs of personid who have the same hobbies( same hobby_id ).

If A has hobby_id 1, B has too, if A doesn't have hobby_id 2, B doesn't have too, we will output A & B 's person_ids.

If A and B and C reach the limits, we output A & B , B & C, A & C.

I've finished in a very very very stupid method, multiple joins the table itself and multiple sub-queries. And of course be laughed by leader.

Is there any high performance method in a SQL for this question?

I have been thinking hard for this since 36 hrs ago......

---

sample data in mysql dump

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_hobby` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hobby_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `tbl_hobby` (`person_id`, `hobby_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(2, 2),
(2, 3),(2, 4),(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3),(3, 4),
(4, 1),(4, 3),(4, 4),(5, 1),(5, 5),(5, 9),
(6, 2),(6, 3),(6, 4),(7, 1),(7, 3),(7, 7),
(8, 2),(8, 3),(8, 4),(9, 1),(9, 2),(9, 3),
(9, 4),(10, 1),(10, 5),(10, 9),(10, 11);
COMMIT;
```

Expert result: (2 and 6 and 8 same, 3 and 9 same)

```
2,6
2,8
6,8
3,9
```

Order of result records and order of the two number in one record is not important. Result record in one column or in two columns are all accepted since it can be easily concated or seperated.

Comment: sample data and the expected output please.

Comment: So if A has hobbies 1, 2, and 3, then you are looking for another person with exactly those three hobbies, 1, 2, and 3, no less, no more. Correct?

Comment: For which DBMS are you asking? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: You can create a string per each user -comma delimited, sorted list of hobbies. Then this task becomes easy - for example you can join based on this new field to find users with the same hobbies.

Comment: please give sample of you desired output.

Comment: Comma separated data?!? That's not the way SQL works...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, make it easy to help you - and you'll get better answers, faster.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes it is. It's the easiest solution. Just use a string aggregating function to get a hobbies string per person. In PostgreSQL you could also build an array instead, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, sample data is late.

Comment: This is a good read https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala sample data and experted result appended.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner take 5.7 for example.

Comment: Okay, no `WITH` clause hence. MySQL 8.0 has many improvements, so I had to ask.

Comment: So you are looking for which there exists a person for which there does not exists a unequal hobby. (Bit of a mouthful I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate per person to get strings of their hobbies. Then aggregate per hobby list find out which belong to more than one person.

```
select hobbies, group_concat(person_id order by person_id) as persons
from
(
  select person_id, group_concat(hobby_id order by hobby_id) as hobbies
  from tbl_hobby
  group by person_id
) persons
group by hobbies
having count(*) > 1
order by hobbies;
```

This gives a a list of persons per hobby. Which is the easiest way to output a solution as we would otherwise have to build all possible pairs.

**UPDATE:** If you want pairs, you'll have to query the table twice:

```
select p1.person_id as person 1, p2.person_id as person2
from
(
  select person_id, group_concat(hobby_id order by hobby_id) as hobbies
  from tbl_hobby
  group by person_id
) p1
join
(
  select person_id, group_concat(hobby_id order by hobby_id) as hobbies
  from tbl_hobby
  group by person_id
) p2 on p2.person_id > p1.person_id and p2.hobbies = p1.hobbies
order by person1, person2;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked as experted. I'll study for it in 5 hours because it is 3:22am in China.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative version, without using any proprietary string handling:

```
select distinct t1.person_id, t2.person_id
from tbl_hobby t1
join tbl_hobby t2
  on t1.person_id < t2.person_id
where 2 = all (select count(*)
               from tbl_hobby 
               where person_id in (t1.person_id, t2.person_id)
               group by hobby_id);
```

Perhaps less efficient, but portable!